# How to select entire current line inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    var ch;
    while(ch !== "\n"){
        selection?.modify('extend', 'backward', 'character');
        ch = selection.toString()[0];
    }
  var chh;
  selection = window.getSelection();
  while(chh !== "\n"){
        selection?.modify('extend', 'forward', 'character');
        let str = selection?.toString();
        chh = str.substr(str.length - 1);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre contenteditable>
This is the first line

This is the second line
This is the third line

This is the fourth line
</pre>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Clicking on the button I need to select the current line - i.e. the line where the cursor is placed.

Please place your cursor inside the word `second` or `third` and click the button.

You'll see that only right side of line is selected instead of entire line.

Another problem is with `first` and `fourth` line because there is no "\n" character on the beginning / end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `extend`, you are changing the focus - not the anchor - of the selection range. This means the second `modify` still uses the original anchor.

Use `move` to move the anchor.

`lineboundary` checks for the end of a line, so you don't need to check for `\n`.

```js
$('pre').on('click', function() {
let selection = window.getSelection();
selection.modify('move', 'backward', 'lineboundary');
selection.modify('extend', 'forward', 'lineboundary');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre contenteditable>
This is the first line

This is the second line
This is the third line

This is the fourth line
</pre>
```